# How Do I Save Multiple Values In One Database Row

Tags: php, sql, database, rows

I have made a form which allows a user to book a room by selecting a time, a time duration and one of two rooms when a room has been booked the form will show the room as being booked but this happens after 1 booking and I would like 20 users to be able to book a room at say 1:00

this is where I think I need to change something but not to sure.

```
$sql = "
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_list (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
status int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;";
dbDelta( $sql );

$sql= "INSERT INTO table_list (id, title, status) VALUES
(1, 'Room 1', 0),
(2, 'Room 2', 0);";
dbDelta( $sql );
```

How can I set it so i can have multiple users booking the same room at the same time?

Comment: I think you want to look at some table design here (do some of your own research on StackExchange)...you'll most likely want three tables, one to hold the room information (like you have here), one to have user information, and then a 'bookings' table that holds the room_id and user_id along with booking information like time/duration.  I'm a bit confused as to why you'd want 20 users to be able to book at one time though.

Comment: Im really new to creating databases.. the room availability is like a conference room so 20 could book into room 1 and 20 could book into room 2

Answer (score 1):

You will want to divide this into three tables and handle your problem with a one to many relationship.  You will want a 'rooms' table that simply holds an ID number and some brief information on what that room is (like you have here, a name and ID is fine).  You will want a second table as 'users'...just like rooms, this will hold an ID field for each user and some information on that user as you see fit.  You then have a bookings table that stores something a long the lines of 'room_id, user_id,datetime_booked'.  Each row in the bookings table represents a single booking.  Things like 'duration' (perhaps start_date and end_date to allow flexible booking lengths) or 'number of people' could also be added this if you want the additional functionality.

User information doesn't actually have to be stored as it's own seperate table...'booking' could have the user information in it, but each time that user creates a booking, you'll have their user information restored in the database (redundant lines).  The user table eliminates this data redundancy and replaces it with an ID column.

Hopefully you see how that set up works...Give some research (stack overflow is a great resource) into table normalization and how one to many relations work.